# Calculating the partial derivative and plugging in interval given.

Tags: numerical-methods

I have dervied: $$H_0=3(\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha})^2-2(\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha})^3,$$
$$H_1=3(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha})^2-2(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha})^3,$$
$$S_0=(\frac{(\beta-x)^2}{\beta-\alpha})-(\frac{(\beta-x)^3}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}),$$
$$S_1=(-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{\beta-\alpha})+(\frac{(x-\alpha)^3}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}),$$ I am supposed to get $$\\
H_0'(\alpha) = 0, \quad H_1'(\alpha) = 0, \quad S_0'(\alpha) = 1,\quad S_1'(\alpha) = 0
\\
H_0'(\beta) = 0, \quad H_1'(\beta) = 0, \quad S_0'(\beta) = 0,\quad S_1'(\beta) = 1
$$ when I take the derivative but when I calculate it for example for H_0 and then plug in [a,b] for x, I get a zero in the denominator both times and that is undefined and incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by and then plug in $ [a,b]$ for $x$?

Comment: I think he means $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: yes sorry in my textbook they are used interchangably, but basically when I plug in first alpha for the derivative of H_0 I get a zero in the denominator which is not giving me the results I am supposed to get. @Andrei

Comment: You don't have $x$ in the denominator, so it will always be some power of $(\alpha-\beta)$

Comment: @Cherry: I get $$H_0'(x) = \dfrac{6 (\beta-x)^2}{(\beta-\alpha)^3}-\dfrac{6 (\beta-x)}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}$$ This results in $H_0'(x) = 0$ when substituting $x = \alpha$ or $x = \beta$. Does you derivative work out to that? Fix that and problem will be resolved and you'll have the same issue with all other derivatives.

Comment: Yes sorry I was plugging in for values of x that were not present. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$H'_0(x)=-6\frac{\beta-x}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}+6\frac{(\beta-x)^2}{(\beta-\alpha)^3}$$
If I calculate $H'(\alpha)$ I get:
$$H'(\alpha)=-6\frac{\beta-\alpha}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}+6\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^2}{(\beta-\alpha)^3}=0$$
Also, numerators for both terms are zero when $x=\beta$

Comment: Oh I am so silly, I was plugging in a and b in the denominator despite there not being an x value. Thank you for the help!